# Ruby on Rails form_for select field with class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beating my head against the wall on this one. I want to make a simple select tag using the `f.select` tag but nothing I do works. I put an example below:

```
<%= f.select(:object_field, ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 4'], :class => 'my_style_class')%>
```

Ok, so basically it is a simple list that once the form is submitted it places the value into the `object_field`. That all works, but viewing the page source the class tag is not included. It doesn't throw an error, it just skips it all together.

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<%= f.select(:object_field, ['Item 1', ...], {}, { :class => 'my_style_class' }) %>
```

`select` helper takes two options hashes, one for select, and the second for html options. So all you need is to give default empty options as first param after list of items and then add your class to `html_options`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Comment: I had tried this way in haml but don't know why in "Inspect Element in firebug with element" class is not seen here is my code = f.select(:gender,[['Male', true], ['Female', false]],{},{:class=>"drop",:style=>"opacity: 0;"})

Comment: @GaganGami I got it to work with this code:             `= f.select(:stars, [['Male', true], ['Female', false]], {}, {:class=>"form-control",:style=>"opacity: 0;"}) ` opacity set to 0 will render your field invisible.

Comment: Does anyone know what we should do if the f.select is being passed a block in the end? The class doesn't seem to go through with any combination I've tried.

Answer (score 32):

You can also add prompt option like this.

```
<%= f.select(:object_field, ['Item 1', 'Item 2'], {include_blank: "Select something"}, { :class => 'my_style_class' }) %>
```

Answer (score 14):

This work for me

```
<%= f.select :status, [["Single", "single"], ["Married", "married"], ["Engaged", "engaged"], ["In a Relationship", "relationship"]], {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can see in here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select

Or here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Select tag has maximun 4 agrument, and last agrument is html option, it mean you can put class, require, selection option in here.

```
= f.select :sms_category_id, @sms_category_collect, {}, {class: 'form-control', required: true, selected: @set}
```

Comment: `selected: @set` works for me when I put it in the first `{}`.