# Rails Option Select :class not being applied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please tell me how I should fix this option/select menu. My poor syntax must be stopping `:class =>"sign-pay-lm1"` from being applied.

```
<span class="signup-label-paying">
  <%= select "payments", "expiry_month", User::MONTH_NAMES.collect{|x| [x, User::MONTH_NAMES.index(x) + 1] }, :class =>"sign-pay-lm1" %>
</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails form\_for select field with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<span class="signup-label-paying"><%= select "payments", "expiry_month", User::MONTH_NAMES.collect{|x| [x, User::MONTH_NAMES.index(x) + 1] }, {}, { :class =>"sign-pay-lm1"} %>
```

Indeed `html_options` is the last hash. [See doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).

Comment: Ahhh I figured I was missing something in the set of hashes.. What is this {} for?

Comment: @IanMason You passed your html options (the :class => 'foobar') as the 4th argument. The `select` form helper method expects them to be the 5th argument. Since you don't have any options for the select, you just pass it an empty hash (`{}`). :)