# How to add class attribute to select tag in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, html-select

I want to add class attribute to select tag in rails 3
my code is

```
<div >
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.select "type_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@type,
    "type_id","name"),:include_blank=>true%>

</div>
```

My problem is that I want to add one specific class name to this select tag for validation purpose.
I tried adding

```
  :class=>"myclassname"
```

but it not worked for me.plz resolve my issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails form\_for select field with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add class attribute like this. Check [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

```
<%= f.select "type_id", 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@type, "type_id","name"), 
    { :include_blank => true }, 
    { :class => 'myclassname' } %>
```

Comment: Great thatz worked fine for me .My problem  was I not used the braces{} around the :include_blank=>true and :class=>"myclass"...Thanks once again Kulbir

Comment: I face this issue myself many a times. I keep forgetting the braces :)