# Ruby f.select: Syntax for assigning css class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

**ENVIRONMENT**

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]; Rails 3.2.6; OSX 10.6.8

**QUESTION**

Having tried many permutations of the following syntax, I have to ask (the probably stupid question), **what is the proper syntax for assigning .css classes to Ruby f.select objects?**

```
<%= f.select :fieldname, 
options_for_select( [[ t('selector_instruction_string'), ""]] + countries, 
resource.fieldname), 
html_options { :class => 'Select_100pct' } %>
```

**See last line (broken for display).**

**This syntax (and many like it) are either ignored, or fail to raise errors (either).**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails form\_for select field with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To me it seems that, when I read the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/actionpack/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder:select), your code should be:

```
<%= f.select :fieldname, options_for_select(...), {}, { :class => 'Select_100pct' } %>
```

Because you only want to specify `html_options`, just pass in an empty Hash `{}` for `options`.