# add class to rails select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I need to add a class to my select.It seems to be easy but I'm not able to figure it out.

I'm trying this but the class doesn't show up:

```
<%= f.select :dr_state, us_states ,:selected=>cr_dovi.try(:dr_state),:class=>"dr_state"  %>
```

When I don't need to make that select auto-select It works in this way:

```
 <%= f.select :dr_state, us_states ,{},:class=>"dr_state" %>
```

I have been trying to figure it out for about an hour please help me.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-select-with-class

Comment: @mdepolli Its not a duplicate my question is different than his. I hope you have read it properly...

Comment: As you can now see from the very similar answers, this is indeed a duplicate of the referenced question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, I think Ruby may be parsing both of your final parameters into the same hash:

```
<%= f.select :dr_state, us_states , { :selected=>cr_dovi.try(:dr_state) }, :class=>"dr_state" %>
```