# Can't add class on select form helper in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4. Can't seem to add `class` to `select`. I think other attributes like `required`, `autofocus` are also not there:

```
<%= form.select "availability", options_for_select(1..200), required: 'true', autofocus: 'true', class: 'form-control' %>
```

Output is below:

```
<select id="event_availability" name="event[availability]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails form\_for select field with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= form.select "availability", options_for_select(1..200), {}, {required: 'true', autofocus: 'true', class: 'form-control'} %>
```

Possible options for third argument are `:prompt` and `:include_blank`

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: Yes, totally forgot there are two options hashes for this helper. The first is `select` helper specific and the second is for the general `form` helper options.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me 
Pull List:

```
<%= f.select( :user_id,    options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :name, (@user.id.nil?) ? nil : @users.id), { :include_blank => true },  {:class => 'span4'}) %>
```

Comment: But I can do the same thing for select_tag.  Any idea?

Comment: <%= select_tag( "warehouse_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@warehouses, :id, :name, (@warehouse_id.nil?)          ? nil : @warehouse_id),          { :include_blank => false}, {:class => 'span4'}) %>

Answer (score 0):

This  is work fine for me:

```
<%= f.select(:"task_day", ["Today", "Tomorrow", "Day After Tomorrow"], { selected: "Today" }, {required: 'true', class: 'form-control'})  %>
```