# Rails form select doesn't use bootstrap class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have select form field with bootstrap form-control class

```
= f.select(:competition_section, [[], ['Piano'], ['Violin'], ['Cello'], ['Voice']], { :class => "form-control" })
```

but select for some reason don't use that class. Other input fields are working fine with this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
= f.select(:competition_section, [[], ['Piano'], ['Violin'], ['Cello'], ['Voice']],{}, { :class => "form-control" })
```

From this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class) question

Comment: @user3392082  Accept the answer if it worked for you so that others will not waste time by reading the question.