# How to create select tag in form_for Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, form-for

I am trying to create a select tag in a form_for where I can select multiple categories from the options. I have looked at the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags) and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class), but neither of them seem to work. So far, I have this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="form-control" multiple title="Choose Department(s)" data-size="5">
   <%= options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name)%>
</select>
```

And my form_for looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}) do |f| %>
```

My listings can have many categories. How am I supposed to make this save to my form? Right now, the categories aren't saving when I submit my form.

Comment: So, you have the problem with selecting multiple items right?

Comment: No, the select tag is working properly. I can select multiple categories, but it isn't saving to the database when I submit the form.

Comment: What's the field name? Also post some ruby codes and paramters.

Comment: You should probably use a select helper to generate the select tag as there are most likely missing attributes needed for persisting the data. `<%= select_tag :department_id, class: 'selectpicker', multiple: true, ...etc %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because your select isn't scoped to your `@listing` object. Try:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
```

To address @ddubs's comment suggesting to replace the `select` tag with a Rails form helper as well as keeping your custom HTML data attributes:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose Department(s)", multiple: true, data: { style: "form-control", size: "5" }) %>
```

For more information on `collection_select` options, look at the [Rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).

Comment: So I put `<%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, class: "selectpicker", data-style: "form-control", multiple: true, title: "Choose Department(s)", data-size: "5") %> ` and it is throwing an error. I think this is because of the hyphen in data-style and data-size. Any idea how I can make this be recognized as an attribute of the select tag that I want to change?

Comment: Updated my answer. You can pass custom HTML attributes (e.g. HTML5 `data-`) with something like `data: { size: 5, style: 'form-control' }`.

Comment: I ended up using  `<%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name,{:"data-style" => "form-control", multiple: true, :"data-size" => "5"}, {class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose Department(s)"}) %> `. Now the only problem is the "multiple" is not working.

Comment: How are you saving the array of `category_ids` in your controller? Assuming you're using [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html), you'd have to first replace `category_ids` with `category_id` and declare the permitted param as `category_id: []`

Answer (score 0):

Final answer ended up being `<%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name,{:"data-style" => "form-control", :"data-size" => "5"}, {class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose Department(s)", multiple: true}) %>` as mmichael pointed out.