# Where do I insert a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I'm pretty confused on where to put my `class:'custom-select'` for a select option.

```
<%= form.select(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories)) %>
```

Where does it go?

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: This question had existed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML hash is the fourth argument in the select tag helper method.

```
<%= form.select(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), {}, class: 'custom-select') %>
```

Comment: NP - the arguments are as follows: `select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`