# RAILS - Can't use class in f.select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu, form-for

I have a select form for user specialties that matches the category. I have a select input that looks as follows

```
        <%= f.select(:specialty_ids, Specialty.where(category_id: 2).collect{|x| [x.specname, x.id]}, {}, {:multiple=> true})%>
```

and it  works fine, submits the specialty and saves it in the database. The second I add a class, it all of the sudden breaks. This is what it looks like when I add a class

```
        <%= f.select(:specialty_ids, Specialty.where(category_id: 2).collect{|x| [x.specname, x.id]}, {}, {:multiple=> true, :class=> 'testclass'})%>
```

this also does not work

```
        <%= f.select(:specialty_ids, Specialty.where(category_id: 2).collect{|x| [x.specname, x.id]}, {}, {:class=> "testclass"})%>
```

I have no idea why, but I suspect because it's not properly structured. After a lot of time trying to find a solution to this, I haven't come across one yet. What exactly am I doing wrong? and how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails form\_for select field with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
...}, html: { class: "testclass" }
```