# How to add html class to rails f.select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have found a few similar articles on stack but none of these examples seem to do the trick.

I'm calling map on an object, to create options in an f.select field, and I'm also using Include_blank option, then trying the class and the class will not work.

I've tried the following:

```
<%= f.select(:city_race_id, @city_races.map {|n| [n.office, n.id]}, include_blank: true,  html: { class: "form-control" }) %>
```

and

```
<%= f.select(:city_race_id, @city_races.map {|n| [n.office, n.id]}, include_blank: true, :class => 'form-control' ) %>
```

both render form and doesn't break rails, but neither show styling.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081944/9595653

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on Rails form\_for select field with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081907/ruby-on-rails-form-for-select-field-with-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
  <%= f.select(:city_race_id, @city_races.map {|n| [n.office, n.id]}, {include_blank: "Select something"}, { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

select helper takes two options hashes, one for select, and the second for html options. you can also add prompt option.

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a saint. I see how it works now with the curly {} brackets. :)